# What (foo(), val) expression in C does?

Tags: c, assignment-operator

In this snippet of C90:

```c
extern float foo();

int bar(int a) {
    int b = (foo(), a); // <- this line
    return b;
}
```

Will `foo()` be evaluated?
What will happen to its return value?

Comment: It's the same thing as the far more well-written `{ foo(); return a; }`

Comment: Where did you find that little _gem_?

Comment: @thebusybee in gcc testsuite, but there were no clarification, what this snippet was supposed to do.